# Get a list of outlook shared contacts using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm writing a program and i need to get the list of my shared contacts from my outlook. I wrote a code that returns a list of my contacts (not the shared).
how can I get the shared contacts?

this is my code:

Private Sub GetListOfContacts(cmb As ComboBox)

```
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()
    Dim contactItemsList As List(Of Outlook.ContactItem) = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim folderSuggestedContacts As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = Nothing
    Dim folderContacts As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing
    Dim itemObj As Object = Nothing
    Dim contact As Outlook.ContactItem

    Try
        contactItemsList = New List(Of Outlook.ContactItem)()
        ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        'getting items from the Contacts folder in Outlook
        folderContacts = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)
        folderItems = folderContacts.Items
        For i As Integer = 1 To folderItems.Count
            itemObj = folderItems(i)
            If (TypeOf (itemObj) Is Outlook.ContactItem) Then
                contact = itemObj
                cmb.Items.Add(contact.FullName)
            Else
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(itemObj)
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you share the contacts ... are you sharing a sub folder in your contacts folder in outlook or do you share a different folder all together ?

Comment: the shared contacts it's another user's contacts that he share with me. I dont familiar with the share options. what is the difference between the folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` and pass the Recipient object retrieved from `Namespace.CreateRecipient`.

```
Dim recip as Outlook.Recipient
...
recip = ns.CreateRecipient("SomeExchangeUserName")
folderContacts = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)
```

Comment: I have tried to do that. to no avail. can you show me how to code it right? thanks a lot